# css animation linear stop for 2s when display new <li>

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

The code right now is moving up without pause when it shows the <li> content. How do I pause between keyframes?

```css
li {
  line-height: 50px;
}

#list-container {
  animation: li_move forwards 10s linear 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes li_move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(calc((100% - 50px)*-1));
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your animation is not working. Please give us proper code or explain about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try duplicating the states.

```
  11.8% {transform: translateY(-50px);}
  17.7% {transform: translateY(-50px);}
```

Let's suppose we stop the animation for 2s as requested and animate for 1s in between. We have 5 animations * 3 = (total of 15)  + 2 extra seconds.

```
animation: li_move forwards 17s ease-out
```

1s of animation is 100%/17 = 5.9%. Every 5.9% of the animation, the animation will last for 1sec. We can make an excel spreahseet so we can visualise it better and enter numbers with ease. [image: calculating with excel easily]

```css
li {
  line-height: 50px;
}

#list-container {
  animation: li_move forwards 17s ease-out 
  1s infinite;
}

@keyframes li_move {
  0% {transform: translateY(0);}
  11.8% {transform: translateY(-50px);}
  17.7% {transform: translateY(-50px);}
  29.5% {transform: translateY(-100px);}
  35.4% {transform: translateY(-100px);}
  47.2% {transform: translateY(-150px);}
  53.1% {transform: translateY(-150px);}
  64.9% {transform: translateY(-200px);}
  70.8% {transform: translateY(-200px);}
  82.5% {transform: translateY(-250px);}
  88.5% {transform: translateY(-250px);}
  88.500001% {transform: translateY(0);}
}
```

```html
<div id="list-container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Optional: You can also pause an animation with hovering your mouse over the div:

```
#list-container:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: when it gets to 6 and animating to 1, can make 1 pause? as after 6 then when it gets to 1 it will immediately animate to 2

Comment: I showed you how I calculated the numbers for animated stops. I added an extra jump  88.500001% {transform: translateY(0);} it just skips the frames so it doesn't animate to the start. Waits 2 second of animation before starting the cycle again.